# Hadoop streaming with C# and Mono : IdentityMapper being used incorrectly

Tags: c#, mono, hadoop-streaming

I have mapper and reducer executables written in C#.
I want to use these with Hadoop streaming.

This is the command I'm using to create the Hadoop job...

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-*.jar 
-input "/user/hduser/ss_waits" 
-output "/user/hduser/ss_waits-output" 
–mapper "mono mapper.exe" 
–reducer "mono reducer.exe" 
-file "mapper.exe" 
-file "reducer.exe"
```

This is the error encountered by each mapper...

```
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1014)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:592)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper.map(IdentityMapper.java:38)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Based on the call-stack, the problem seems to be that the (Java) IdentityMapper class is being used as the mapper. (Which explains why the type mismatch error was caused). **The mapper should have been the executable "mono mapper.exe".**

Any ideas why *mono mapper.exe* is not being used?

The mapper.exe and reducer.exe have the following permissions: -rwxr-xr-x

I am able to successfully execute *mono mapper.exe* from the unix command shell and have it read in text from stdin and write to stdout.

**Environment:**

- Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS (VM running on Azure)
- Hadoop 1.0.4
- Mono 2.10

Comment: A trivial suggestion: If you're splitting your job submission command across multiple lines, are you writing \ at the end of each line (other than the last)?

Comment: You can also try: create the wrapping script (http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications#Shell_Scripts) or create bundle (http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications#Bundles)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming mono is in the PATH, do you need the full path to mapper.exe and reducer.exe? i.e.

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-*.jar 
-input "/user/hduser/ss_waits" 
-output "/user/hduser/ss_waits-output" 
–mapper "mono /path/to/mapper.exe" 
–reducer "mono /path/to/reducer.exe" 
-file "mapper.exe" 
-file "reducer.exe"
```